# Video stream (MPEG4 video) not showing on android using MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, video-streaming

There is an online stream that is 512Kb MPEG4 and total size of 312mb online and if I'm correct after looking over docs in order to play the movie I just simply put:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
Try{
  mp.setDataSource("http://site.com/movie.mp4");
}
Try {
  mp.prepare();
}
mp.start();
```

It is triggered to play after a button press which after a few seconds after pressing the button it plays the audio BUT doesn't show the video, why not?  Do I have to use a surface view or something for visual playback of the stream (the android docs don't seem to help me much)?

Comment: Encountered this a while ago. The video is your own or is a 3rd-party's?

Comment: 3rd Party, Public Domain.  Why do you ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, yes, you need a `SurfaceView` to play back video with a `MediaPlayer`. Or, use a `VideoView` and skip the `MediaPlayer`.

Second, if you are trying to play this back in the emulator, this is typical behavior. Video playback will not work well on the emulator unless you have crazy-fast hardware. I recommend that video player development be done with actual Android devices.